# The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection - command.Parameters.Clear() does not work

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, exception, ado.net

I am getting desperate here. I cant figure out why does this exception occur. I searched and read about this problem and it seems everyone managed to solve it with command.Parameters.Clear(), but this does not work for me. Here is my code:

```
    public class ProductsDataAccess : Connection 
{
    public static SqlParameter[] createParams(Products prod)
    {
        SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@id", prod.prodID);
        idParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
        idParam.Size = 45;
        idParam.IsNullable = false;
        idParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter("@name", prod.prodName);
        nameParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
        nameParam.Size = 45;
        nameParam.IsNullable = false;
        nameParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter demandParam = new SqlParameter("@demand", prod.demand);
        demandParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        demandParam.IsNullable = false;
        demandParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter demandLTParam = new SqlParameter("@demandLT", prod.demandLT);
        demandLTParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        demandLTParam.IsNullable = false;
        demandLTParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter leadTimeParam = new SqlParameter("@leadTime", prod.leadTime);
        leadTimeParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        leadTimeParam.IsNullable = false;
        leadTimeParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter fixedCoastParam = new SqlParameter("@k", prod.k);
        fixedCoastParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Float;
        fixedCoastParam.IsNullable = false;
        fixedCoastParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter cParam = new SqlParameter("@c", prod.c);
        cParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Float;
        cParam.IsNullable = false;
        cParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter chPrecentageParam = new SqlParameter("@chPrecent", prod.precentOfC);
        chPrecentageParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        chPrecentageParam.IsNullable = false;
        chPrecentageParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter chParam = new SqlParameter("@ch", prod.ch);
        chParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Float;
        chParam.IsNullable = false;
        chParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter optimalQParam = new SqlParameter("@q", prod.q);
        optimalQParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        optimalQParam.IsNullable = false;
        optimalQParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter annualChParam = new SqlParameter("@annualCh", prod.annualCh);
        annualChParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Float;
        annualChParam.IsNullable = false;
        annualChParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter annualKParam = new SqlParameter("@annualK", prod.annualK);
        annualKParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Float;
        annualKParam.IsNullable = false;
        annualKParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter optimalTACParam = new SqlParameter("@tac", prod.tac);
        optimalTACParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Float;
        optimalTACParam.IsNullable = false;
        optimalTACParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter rParam = new SqlParameter("@r", prod.r);
        rParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        rParam.IsNullable = false;
        rParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter inventoryLvlParam = new SqlParameter("@invLvl", prod.inventoryLvl);
        inventoryLvlParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        inventoryLvlParam.IsNullable = false;
        inventoryLvlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter statusParam = new SqlParameter("@status", prod.status);
        statusParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
        statusParam.Size = 10;
        statusParam.IsNullable = false;
        statusParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter[] paramList = {idParam, nameParam, demandParam, demandLTParam,
                                   leadTimeParam, fixedCoastParam, cParam,
                                   chPrecentageParam, chParam, optimalQParam,
                                   annualChParam, annualKParam, optimalTACParam, 
                                   rParam, inventoryLvlParam, statusParam };
        return paramList;

    }

    public static void insertProduct(Products product)
    {


        String comStr = "insert into Products(prodID, name, demand, demandLT, leadTime, fixedCoast, " + 
            "c, chAsPrecentage, ch, optimalQ, annualCh, annualK, optimalTAC, r, inventoryLvl, prodStatus) " + 
            "values(@id, @name, @demand, @demandLT, @leadTime, @k, @c, @chPrecent, " + 
            "@ch, @q, @annualCh, @annualK, @tac, @r, @invLvl, @status)";

        createConncetion();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comStr, con);
        command.Parameters.AddRange(createParams(product));

        openConnection();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        closeConnection();

        command.Parameters.Clear()
        command.Dispose();
    }

    public static DataTable getAllProducts()
    {
        String comStr = "select prodID, name, demand, demandLT, leadTime, fixedCoast, c, chAsPrecentage, " + 
            "ch, optimalQ, annualCh, annualK, optimalTAC, r, inventoryLvl, prodStatus from Products";

        createConncetion();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comStr, con);

        DataTable table = new DataTable("allProduct");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand=command;

        openConnection();

        adapter.Fill(table);
        command.Dispose();
        closeConnection();
        return table;
    }

}
```

Here is the other class in which I am using sqlParameters:

```
    public class StatisticsDataAccess : Connection
{

    public static SqlParameter[] createParams(Statistics stat, string prodID)
    {

        SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@id", prodID);
        idParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
        idParam.Size = 45;
        idParam.IsNullable = false;
        idParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m1Param = new SqlParameter("@m1", stat.month1);
        m1Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m1Param.IsNullable = false;
        m1Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m2Param = new SqlParameter("@m2", stat.month2);
        m2Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m2Param.IsNullable = false;
        m2Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m3Param = new SqlParameter("@m3", stat.month3);
        m3Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m3Param.IsNullable = false;
        m3Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m4Param = new SqlParameter("@m4", stat.month4);
        m4Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m4Param.IsNullable = false;
        m4Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m5Param = new SqlParameter("@m5", stat.month5);
        m5Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m5Param.IsNullable = false;
        m5Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m6Param = new SqlParameter("@m6", stat.month6);
        m6Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m6Param.IsNullable = false;
        m6Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m7Param = new SqlParameter("@m7", stat.month7);
        m7Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m7Param.IsNullable = false;
        m7Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m8Param = new SqlParameter("@m8", stat.month8);
        m8Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m8Param.IsNullable = false;
        m8Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m9Param = new SqlParameter("@m9", stat.month9);
        m9Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m9Param.IsNullable = false;
        m9Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m10Param = new SqlParameter("@m10", stat.month10);
        m10Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m10Param.IsNullable = false;
        m10Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m11Param = new SqlParameter("@m11", stat.month11);
        m11Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m11Param.IsNullable = false;
        m11Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter m12Param = new SqlParameter("@m12", stat.month12);
        m12Param.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
        m12Param.IsNullable = false;
        m12Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        SqlParameter[] paramList = {idParam, m1Param, m2Param, m3Param, m4Param,
                                   m5Param, m6Param, m7Param, m8Param, m8Param,
                                   m10Param, m11Param, m12Param };
        return paramList;
    }

    public static void insertStatistic(Statistics stat, string prodID)
    {


        String comStr = "insert into LTDStatistic(prodID, month1, month2, month3, month4, month5, " +
            "month6, month7, month8, month9, month10, month11, month12)" +
            "values(@id, @m1, @m2, @m3, @m4, @m5, @m6, @m7, @m8, @m9, @m10, @m11, @m12)";

        createConncetion();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(comStr, con);
        command.Parameters.AddRange(createParams(stat, prodID));

        openConnection();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        closeConnection();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Dispose();

    }

}
```

WCF Service uses methods from those classes in order to modify a data base

```
        public void create(ProductsData product)
    {

        Statistics statDLT = new Statistics(product.demandLTStat.month1, product.demandLTStat.month2,
            product.demandLTStat.month3, product.demandLTStat.month4, product.demandLTStat.month5,
            product.demandLTStat.month6, product.demandLTStat.month7, product.demandLTStat.month8,
            product.demandLTStat.month9, product.demandLTStat.month10, product.demandLTStat.month11,
            product.demandLTStat.month12);

        Products newProd = new Products(product.prodID, product.prodName,
            product.leadTime, product.k, product.c, product.precentOfC, 
            product.demand, statDLT);

        newProd.callculate();
        newProd.determineR();
        ProductsDataAccess.insertProduct(newProd);
        //String plsWork = newProd.prodID;
        StatisticsDataAccess.insertStatistic(newProd.demandLTStat, newProd.prodID);
    }
```

Maybe Im missing some important aspect of how things work ... I dont know. Hope someone can help me, and sorry for the long code segments.

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see which parameter is causing the issue?

Comment: Yes I did, and I saw that the parameter collection of the command is empty at the end of the respective method. I cant see the exact parameter which causes the exception which occurs at the following line:
command.Parameters.AddRange(createParams(stat, prodID));
I will try adding the parameters one by one and see if something new pops out.

Comment: You need place using blocks for your connection and your commands.  This will always ensure the Dispose methods are called properly.  Which class is the error occurring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m8Param` occurs twice in the array returned by `StatisticsDataAccess.createParams()`.

Comment: Thank you for the help that was it !
Such an embarrassing error :(

Answer (score 5):

```
 SqlParameter[] paramList = {
            idParam, m1Param, m2Param, m3Param, m4Param,                            
            m5Param, m6Param, m7Param, **m8Param**, **m8Param**,
                             m10Param, m11Param, m12Param };
```