# Entity Framework Context SqlQuery<T> for a stored procedure returns The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I need to move the filtering of a complex Entity from Linq to SQL to a stored procedure because I am needing to load the data into memory to apply some of the filters with a ToList(). The Linq query causes some searches to timeout. When I switched to a stored procedure, I changes the function thusly:

```
    private IQueryable<ProposalLogVM> ApplyProposalSearch(IndexSearchVM search)
    {
        SqlParameter YearCode;
        SqlParameter ProposalStatus;
        SqlParameter Company;
        SqlParameter SearchString;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.SearchString) && search.Year == null)
        {
            search.Year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.Year.ToString()))
        {
            YearCode = new SqlParameter("@Year", search.Year.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            YearCode = new SqlParameter("@Year", DBNull.Value);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.ProposalStatus))
        {
            ProposalStatus = new SqlParameter("@ProposalStatus", search.ProposalStatus);
        }
        else
        {
            ProposalStatus = new SqlParameter("@ProposalStatus", DBNull.Value);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.CompanyID.ToString()))
        {
            Company = new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", search.CompanyID.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Company = new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", DBNull.Value);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.SearchString))
        {
            SearchString = new SqlParameter("@SearchString", search.SearchString);
        }
        else
        {
            SearchString = new SqlParameter("@SearchString", DBNull.Value);
        }

        var proposals = _dbpm.Database.SqlQuery<ProposalLogVM>("EXEC spSearchProposals @Year, @ProposalStatus, @CompanyID, @SearchString", YearCode, ProposalStatus, Company, SearchString).AsQueryable();

        switch (search.SortOption)
        {
            case "ProposalNumber":
                proposals = proposals.OrderBy(p => p.ProposalNumber);
                break;
            case "ProjectName":
                proposals = proposals.OrderBy(p => p.ProjectName);
                break;
            case "ProjectNameD":
                proposals = proposals.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProjectName);
                break;
            case "BidDate":
                proposals = proposals.OrderBy(p => p.BidDate);
                break;
            case "BidDateD":
                proposals = proposals.OrderByDescending(p => p.BidDate);
                break;
            case "Owner":
                proposals = proposals.OrderBy(p => p.Owner);
                break;
            case "OwnerD":
                proposals = proposals.OrderByDescending(p => p.Owner);
                break;
            default:
                proposals = proposals.OrderByDescending(p => p.ProposalNumber);
                break;
        }

        return proposals;

    }
```

Now I get the "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection." when executing the line

```
        // get the raw proposal list, but don't execute or copy to memory
        IQueryable<ProposalLogVM> rawProposals = ApplyProposalSearch(viewModel.Search);

        // Allow ToPagedList() to do the hard work
        viewModel.Proposals = rawProposals.ToPagedList((int)viewModel.Search.Page, (int)viewModel.Search.Lines);
```

If I just execute the line:

```
        var proposals = _dbpm.Database.SqlQuery<ProposalLogVM>("spSearchProposals @Year, @ProposalStatus, @CompanyID, @SearchString", YearCode, ProposalStatus, Company, SearchString).AsQueryable().ToList();
```

It runs fine and returns all 390,000 records that are expected.

I have spent the past few hours reading all of the other relates Stack Overflow articles and trying those solutions and none seem to work.

Comment: Hi. I'm note sure about your scenario. Next answer will not help you to solve your problem but may help to understand it bit better https://stackoverflow.com/a/29512383/5649561

Comment: Can you show the code of 'ToPagedList'?

Comment: It looks like this is a limitation of using the paged list: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308804/the-sqlparameter-is-already-contained-by-another-sqlparametercollection/24758263  comment from jb007, You may need to incorporate the paging into your stored proc. Their example was in EF4, but that limitation likely has carried forward.

Comment: @StevePy That is exactly what I did. Post that as an answer and I will accept it.